# Manipulate the date base in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

hope someone could help me to understand how to solve my question. I have in my  datebase table PAYMENTS like this:

```
| PAYMENTS.PAYMENT | PAYMENTS.TOTAL   |  
| CASH             |1000              |  
| DEBT             |500               | 
| DEBTPAID         |200               |
```

The problem is: `CASH` is calculated as cash from sales plus `DEBTPAID`. So I need to have this data individualy (`CASH-DEBTPAID AS CASH`) in my report.

How can  I do in `iReport` to modify `PAYMENTS.PAYMENT` as I describe above. I much appreciate your support! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use variable for this purpose

Comment: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish//jasperreportswebsite/JR%20Website/jasperreports_tutorial.html & http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_using_variables.html

Comment: thanks, I know what are the variables, but they can not help me.
I have $F(PAYMENTS.PAYMENT) and $F(PAYMENTS.TOTAL) and iREPORT creates a table I mention above...

Comment: I think it need some conditions like: $F(PAYMENTS.PAYMENT).equals("cash") - $F(PAYMENTS.PAYMENT).equals("debtpaid"), but where and how to make this to calculate the row PAYMENTS.TOTAL, it remains for me a big question! thank you for your effort to help me

Comment: my logics says that it is needed to put a condition for $F(PAYMENTS.TOTAL) to take the result from ("cash") and ("debtapaid") and to create an result ("cash") - ("debtapaid") - who has such experience in the past please share, how to do this operation withe jasper-reports?

Comment: Can you explaing me the structure of your table better? You have many rows with three types of payment (cash, debt and debtpaid). You need to calculate total sum for each type of payment and the sum for two types (cash and debtapaid). Am I right?

Comment: In your question this text confuse me: `CASH is calculated as cash from sales plus DEBTPAID`. What is it `sales`?

Comment: I think you need to provide sample data for both the source and for the desired report output. Then it will be clear what variables are needed.

Comment: For ALEX K: It is about software with a database for sales. It calculates sales plus debtpaid as CASH in table PAYMENTS. It is buildin function. But I would like to make a raport where I will have separate CASH, DEBT and DEBTPAID. I suppose I can give a parameter for PAYMENT.TOTAL in case of PAYMENTS.PAYMENT equal CASH to calculate de data AS CASH-DEBTPAID.
-----///---
For MDAHLMAN: Table PAYMENTS contains PAYMENTS.PAYMENT and PAYMENTS.TOTAL , what is inside of two columns I showed them above. I need a calculation in report for Cash to be calculated as TOTAL for CASH minus Total of DEPTPAID...

Comment: @SergiuCostas Can you post the jrxml file? I think the query in this file need to be improved. I've found the solution, but I need the query for the preparing the right answer. What DB are you using (Oracle, MySQL or something else)?

Comment: The data base is MySQL... the report is simple... it has to columns $F(PAYMENTS.PAYMENT) and $F(PAYMENTS.TOTAL)... it looks simple... the report creates two columns - one with forms of payments and another with amount of money corresponding to each payment

Comment: Also, I suppose the solution might be using function PRINT WHEN EXPRESSION, but not sure...

Comment: the query is simple too... it looks like: Select PAYMENTS.PAYMENT, PAYMENTS.TOTAL from PAYMENTS, order by PAYMENTS.PAYMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL would give you a separate record for CASH and DEBT:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN ('CASH', 'DEBTPAID') THEN 'CASH' ELSE PAYMENTS.PAYMENT END AS PAYMENT,
       SUM(PAYMENTS.TOTAL) AS TOTAL

FROM   PAYMENTS

GROUP BY CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN ('CASH', 'DEBTPAID') THEN 'CASH' ELSE PAYMENTS.PAYMENT END
```

Comment: this script chouse from Cash and Debtpaid only CASH. but the task is to calculate CASH as Total from Cash minus Total from Debtpaid. Thank you anyway for your try to help :)

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT  THEN (PAYMENTS.TOTAL FROM PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'cash' - PAYMENTS.TOTAL FROM PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid') ELSE 0 END) AS CASH - it should something like this, please help

Answer (score 1):

This SQL statement will return you the total CASH and total DEBT in a single record.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN ('CASH', 'DEBTPAID') THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL ELSE 0 END)
       AS CASH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'DEBT' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS DEBT

FROM   PAYMENTS
```

This would give you the correct totals based on the data you gave us.

If you wanted separate records it would have to be done a little differently (I could show you).

Comment: I did not check it yet, but logically looks OK, thank you very much for help :)

Comment: it is partially correct, I need CASH to be calculated as CASH minus DEBTPAID

Comment: Sorry, that was my misunderstanding, I was adding DebtPaid to the cash.  I'll post a corrected script.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT= 'CASH' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL ELSE 0 END)
        -
       SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT= 'DEBTPAID' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS CASH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'DEBT' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS DEBT

FROM   PAYMENTS
```

Comment: It is not any diffrence if I do: SELECT PAYMENTS.PAYMENT, PAYMENTS.TOTAL FROM PAYMENTS... the same result.. but I need a variable which it will be calculated as payments.total from CASH minus payments.total from DEBTPAID

Comment: There is a difference.  This query will return 2 columns, 1 for Cash, 1 for Debt.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I keep going around and around on this.

If you are looking for this:

| PAYMENTS.PAYMENT | PAYMENTS.TOTAL   |
| CASH             |800               |
| DEBT             |500               |

This will give you that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN ('CASH', 'DEBTPAID') THEN 'CASH' ELSE PAYMENTS.PAYMENT END PAYMENT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT= 'DEBTPAID' THEN -PAYMENTS.TOTAL ELSE PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) TOTAL

FROM   PAYMENTS

GROUP BY CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN ('CASH', 'DEBTPAID') THEN 'CASH' ELSE PAYMENTS.PAYMENT END
```